# RailsでSeedデータを保存しようとすると、外部キーがNOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

以下のseedデータを追加しようとすると、

> NOT NULL constraint failed: member_images.member_id: INSERT INTO "member_images"

というエラー表示がされますが理由がわかりません。

なお、`0.upto(9)`の部分を`0.upto(8)`にすると保存できます。
つまり、member_imagesテーブルのid1~9までは外部キーが保存できるのですが、id10以上は外部キーが保存されないため`NOT NULL constraint failed`となります。

このエラーで丸一日かかっており、ぜひご教授頂きたいです。 
よろしくお願いいたします。

【テーブル】 
members(参照元,primrykey保持) 
member_images(membersテーブルを参照する)

【seedデータ】

```ruby
names = %w(Taro Jiro Hana John Mike Sophy Bill Alex Mary Tom)
fnames = ["佐藤", "鈴木", "高橋", "田中"]
gnames = ["太郎", "次郎", "花子"]
affiliations = ["東京大学法学部","株式会社リクルート","カヤック"]
intros = ["プログラミングを学びたいと思っています。","JSの効率的な学習方法を教えます。"]
0.upto(9) do |idx|
    member = Member.create(
        name: names[idx],
        full_name: "#{fnames[idx % 4]} #{gnames[idx % 3]}",
        email: "#{names[idx]}@example.com",
        birthday: "1981-12-01",
        gender: [0, 0, 1][idx % 3],
        affiliation: "#{affiliations[idx % 3]}",
        intro: "#{intros[idx % 2]}",
        administrator: (idx == 0),
        password: "password",
        password_confirmation: "password"
    )
    path = Rails.root.join("db/seeds/development", "member#{idx % 3 + 1}.jpg")
    file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path, "image/jpeg", true)
    MemberImage.create(
        member: member,
        uploaded_image: file
    )
end
```

【スキーマ】

```
create_table "member_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id",    null: false
    t.binary   "data"
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    end

    add_index "member_images", ["member_id"], name: "index_member_images_on_member_id"

    create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                            null: false
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.integer  "gender",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.text     "affiliation"
    t.text     "intro"
    t.boolean  "administrator",   default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "hashed_password"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

以下の部分を

```
member = Member.create(
```

このように変更して実行してみてください。

```
member = Member.create!(
```

エラーになっているのはMemberImageをcreateする際に渡しているmemberがDBに保存されていないからだと思います。（↓この部分↓）

```
MemberImage.create(
    member: member,
    uploaded_image: file
)
```

おそらくMember.create時にバリデーションエラーが発生しているのでしょう。`create!`メソッドを使用すれば、バリデーションエラーがあった時に例外が発生するようになるので、なぜ保存できないかが分かります。